# MPMoviePlayerViewController in landscape / all orientations

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, screen-orientation

My questions is really simple, tutorials and answers didn't fix my problem.
I have an app with settings:
[image]

I want support only Portrait/Upside Down orientations in all my viewControllers except when I want to play video via:

> MPMoviePlayerViewController

Here is code:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[Videos videoURL:video.hash]];
if (mp) {
    isVideoPlaying = YES;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(videoFinishedPlaying:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:mp.moviePlayer];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
    mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [mp.moviePlayer play];
    [mp release];
}
```

When `MPMoviePlayerViewController` plays video I want support all orientations.
Need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should permit rotation by the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     // Return YES for supported orientations
}
```

IOS 6:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

put the code in the .m file where you call the player

Comment: Not working, still as it should be I can't rotate in all viewControllers, and the same for VideoViewController where I make movie play. It works only if I set needed orientations in summary tab of xcode project. why?

Comment: What IOS version your app running on?

Comment: I succeeded with iOS 5 and prior. But still have problem with ios6

Comment: In IOS 6 you should use [appDelegate.window setRootViewController: myVC]; in the window and not addsubView, check your appDelegate

Comment: this is how I do it: `self.window.rootViewController = deckController;`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I had same problem I resolved it -

You need to first change in appdelegate:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if ([[[NowPlaying sharedManager] playerViewController] allowRotation])//Place your condition here
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Register Notifications for the full screen control:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then add line of code in the player controller:

```
- (void)moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
               {
                   self.allowRotation = YES;
               });
}



- (void)moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
self.allowRotation = NO;
[self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
               {

                   //Managing GUI in pause condition
                       if (self.currentContent.contentType == TypeVideo && self.moviePlayerController.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
                   {
                       [self.moviePlayerController pause];
                       if (self.playButton.selected)
                           self.playButton.selected = NO;
                   }
                   self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
                   self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
               });
}
```

This code is tested in iOS6 and iOS7 working fine. Thanks